# Undeclared identifier in C function

Tags: c, stack-overflow

When I compile the following C function / program I get errors like `"missing ';' before 'type' 'remainder' : undeclared identifier"` - what is wrong with this function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void conversionTo(int number,int base) {
  if(number==0)
    return;

  int remainder=number%base;    
  conversionTo((number/base),base);
  if(remainder<10)
    printf("%c",'0'+remainder);
  else
    printf("%c",'a'-10+remainder);
}   


int main() {
    conversionTo(int number,int base);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i get errors like missing ';' before 'type'               'remainder' : undeclared identifier

Comment: Didn't use C for a long time, but I think you can't do '0'+remainder this would try to add a string and a number. In main you need to use actual numbers when you call conversionTo like conversionTo(123, 8);

Comment: In the `main function`: `conversionTo(int number,int base)` should be `conversionTo(number, base)`. Apart from that you don't have these variables declared/initialized in the `main` function...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a C expert, but from experience very long ago I believe you cannot declare variables in the middle of a function.

Also, it's unclear what you are trying to do with the function / print statements.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void conversionTo(int number,int base) {
  int remainder=number%base;
  if(number==0)
    return;    

  conversionTo((number/base),base);
  if(remainder<10)
    printf("%c",'0'+ remainder); // Through the way ASCII works that gives the ASCII rep
                                 // of the remainder.
  else
    printf("%c",'a'-10+remainder); // Hex digits (A-F).
}   


int main() {
    conversionTo(/*Any number here*/10, /*any base number here*/2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must use the original `printf("%c",'0'+remainder);` or the function will not work.

Comment: @AndrewQ - thanks for the comment - somehow that triggered an old memory - are my edited comments more correct now?

Comment: Btw, I've checked with gcc 4.1.2 and the position of the declaration has no influence on the compilation and the final output. Maybe the C compiler @ladyd uses has a strict adherence to K&R standard, which forbids to add a declaration 'on the fly'.

Comment: Found: `gcc test_me.c -std=c89 -pedantic -o test_me` throws the error.

Comment: Just FYI, you can in C99 and C11 but not in C89.

Answer (score 2):

You need to defines variables, then they can be used. 
So this:

```
int main() {
  conversionTo(int number,int base);
  return 0;
}
```

should become this:

```
int main(void) 
{
  int number;
  int base:

  number = 47;
  base = 11;

  conversionTo(number, base);

  return 0;
}
```

Also non C99 compliant compilers do not like having variables declared in the middle of a context:

```
void conversionTo(int number,int base) {
  if(number==0)
    return;

  int remainder=number%base;    /* this would fail. */
  conversionTo((number/base),base);
```

To get around this open another context:

```
void conversionTo(int number,int base) {
  if(number==0)
    return;

  {
    int remainder=number%base;    
    conversionTo((number/base),base);
    if(remainder<10)
      printf("%c",'0'+remainder);
    else
      printf("%c",'a'-10+remainder);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your function wrong - pass the arguments this way:

```
conversionTo(2,2);  // assuming you want to convert 2 to binary
```

or

```
int number = 123, base = 10;
conversionTo(number, base); // note this is not the same number and base as in the definition of your conversionTo function
```

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void conversionTo(int number,int base)
{
     if(number==0)

                  return;
     int remainder=number%base;    
     conversionTo((number/base),base);
     if(remainder<10)
         printf("%c",'0'+remainder);
     else
         printf("%c",'a'-10+remainder);
}   

int main()
{

    conversionTo(2,2); // assuming you want to convert 2 to binary
    return 0;

}
```

There are 3 things when using functions:

> Function declaration / prototype - the prototype of your function is:

```
void conversionTo(int ,int );
```

> Function definition:

```
void conversionTo(int number,int base /* Parameter list*/) 
{
    // your functionality
}
```

> Function call where you pass your arguments to your function:

```
conversionTo(2,2);
```

The statement `conversionTo(int number,int base);` simply re-declares it. Try this even this will compile:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    int main();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to invoke your function with a value or variable, not a declaration:

```
conversionTo(123, 10); // using constant value
```

or

```
int number = 123, base = 10; // variable declaration
conversionTo(number, base);  // using variable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
conversionTo(int number, int base)
```

is the syntax for declaring which parameters the function can take. To actually call the function, you need to omit the type (assuming you have variables of the respective name)

```
int number = 5;
int base = 10;

conversionTo(number, base); // <-- no int here!
```

Or you can use numbers directly:

```
conversionTo(5, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition `number` and `base` in your function declaration `void conversionTo(int number, int base)` are the names that the values passed to it will have inside the function. So, if you call `conversionTo(2,5)`, 2 will be seen inside the function as `number`, while 5 will be seen as `base`.

If you want to use variables instead of contants to call the function, you could do that:

```
int main()
{
    int base = 2;
    int number = 5;
    conversionTo(base, number);
    return 0;
}
```

In this confusing example, the variables `base` and `value` have value 2 and 5, respectively. But as you pass them to the function, the values inside it will be number = 2 and base = 5. This shows that those variables are actually different, despite of having the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile with $CC -std=c99, to enable declaring variables in the middle of a block.

(see section 6.8 in the specification)

Answer (score 0):

The declaration "int remainder" must come before any statements in a block.
A declaration may have an initializer as you have here.

You could do:

```
    void conversionTo(int number,int base) {
      if (number > 0) {
        int remainder...
      }
    }
```

since the function will not work with negative numbers.

To fix the other bugs in the routine:

```
    void conversionTo(int number,int base)
    {
      if(number>=0&&base>0&&base<=36)
      {
        int remainder=number%base;    
        number/=base;
        if(number>0)conversionTo(number,base);
        printf("%c",(remainder<10)?'0'+remainder:'a'+remainder-10);
      }
    }
```

This will print a 0 if number is zero and only recurse if needed.